# Craft 2 -> 3 Update /admin 404

Tags: craft3, error-message, 404, updates

I'm attempting to update a craft 2 site to craft 3.

Following these instructions, I used composer to install Craft:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html#if-you-want-your-directory-structure-to-resemble-a-new-craft-3-project%E2%80%A6

I have got to the stage where I go to the domain.com/admin but I am getting the error:

> The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.

Thanks for any help - at a dead end I am sure its something v simple!

Answer (score 1):

Is a lot of potential reasons for what issue may be. Is Craft handling the 404 error? If not, it could be your server is not pointing to the web/index.php properly.

Can check that just putting a die('hello world'); at the top of your index file at least.

Comment: Thanks for your input here. I actually just sorted it after a few hours. basically I installed craft into the wrong directory. Still getting the hang of composer :)